# Density of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in $C^0(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

This could be well-known, but I cannot come up with a rigorous proof. I want to prove density of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in the continuous functions $C^0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in the following sense: given a continuous function $f$, I want to select a smooth function $g$ such that $\sup |f - g|$ is as small as we want. All the tricks I can think of either deal with a compact setting, or continuous functions vanishing at infinity. Thanks!

Comment: But the sup norm isn't even a norm on $C^0(\Bbb R^n)$, so I don't even understand the question.

Comment: @TedShifrin I wanted to say, given any continuous function $f$, we can select a smooth function $g$ such that $\sup |f - g|$ is as small as we want. But you are right. I will rephrase the question.

Comment: By $C^0$ do you mean the continuous functions that vanish at infinity?

Comment: No, @copper.hat, that would be $C^0_0$.

Comment: Just do convolutions with a smooth approximation of the identity.

Comment: @copper.hat No, just continuous functions, to be consistent with the notation $C^k$. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @mathgirl There are continuous functions on $\Bbb R^n$ which aren't bounded. So the norm isn't always properly defined. You could choose some other norm or replace $\Bbb R^n$ with a compact set.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I think you run into problems with many continuous functions' not being in $L^1$. :)

Comment: Perhaps the question should be rephrased as can we uniformly approximate a continuous function by a smooth one? The norm part seems to be a red herring.

Comment: @TedShifrin, no you don't. Convolve with a smooth functions with compact support, of course.This works even with distributions...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Can you write it as an answer with more details? I don't really understand, but I'm interested...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Oh, sloppy of me. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous.

Choose a partition of unity $\{\phi_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is subordinate to some locally finite family $\{U_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of precompact open sets which covers $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then for all $k$, there exists a $C^{\infty}$ function $g_k$ such that $\sup_{x \in \text{supp } \phi_k} |f(x)-g_k(x)|<\epsilon\cdot 2^{-k}$ (we can do this because the support of $\phi_k$ is compact for all $k$, and we know that it's true in the compact case).

Let $g = \sum_k g_k\phi_k$. Then $g$ is $C^{\infty}$, because locally it is the finite sum of $C^{\infty}$ functions.

Since $\sum_k \phi_k=1$, we have that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$,

$$|f(x)-g(x)| = \bigg|\sum_k f(x)\phi_k(x) - g_k(x)\phi_k(x)\bigg| \leq \sum_k |f(x)-g_k(x)|\cdot |\phi_k(x)| \leq \sum_k \epsilon \cdot 2^{-k} = \epsilon$$ Thus $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} |f(x)-g(x)|\leq \epsilon$ and $g$ is $C^{\infty}$, as desired.

Actually, this would work on any manifold (not just $\mathbb{R}^n$), I think.